# How to Recreate Magento 2 backend image upload in frontend

Tags: magento2, file-upload

In Magento 2 there's a single image uploader look like this:

[image]

it uploads the image using AJAX and will return JSON serialized containing the uploaded image information. Is there a way to recreate this functionality in frontend phtml file?

Comment: I haven't tried this but you can check admin module for the same to get the idea of implementation in front end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom extension (let custom extension name is "Vendor_MyModule") for Front-end image uploading.

I assume you already created the custom extension "Vendor_MyModule". So I am  describing here only the necessary files related to image uploading operation.

Please follow below steps .

**step  1:** Create the uploader model file.
***app/code/Vendor/MyMocule/Model/Upload/ImageFileUploader.php***

File : **ImageFileUploader.php**

```
<?php
namespace  Vendor\MyModule\Model\Upload;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class ImageFileUploader
 * @package Aheadworks\Rbslider\Model\Slide
 */
class ImageFileUploader
{
    /**
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const FILE_DIR = 'vendor_mymodule/uplaods';

    /**
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    /**
     * Save file to temp media directory
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveImageToMediaFolder($fileId)
    {
        try {
            $result = ['file' => '', 'size' => ''];
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
            $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem
                ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
                ->getAbsolutePath(self::FILE_DIR);
            /** @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader $uploader */
            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
            $result = array_intersect_key($uploader->save($mediaDirectory), $result);

            $result['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl($result['file']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get file url
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMediaUrl($file)
    {
        $file = ltrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $file), '/');
        return $this->storeManager
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . self::FILE_DIR . '/' . $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get allowed file extensions
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create the Controller to upload the image using the Model created in setp 1

***/app/code/Vendor/MyModule/Controller/Index/UploadImage.php***

File: **UploadImage.php**

```
<?php
    
    namespace  Vendor\MyModule\Controller\Index;
    
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    use Vendor\MyModule\Model\Upload\ImageFileUploader;
    
    class UploadImage extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        
         
        /**
         * @var ImageFileUploader
         */
        private $imageFileUploader;
        
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
        */
        protected $storeManager;
        
    
        /**
         * @param Context $context
         * @param ImageFileUploader $imageFileUploader
         */
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            ImageFileUploader $imageFileUploader
            
        ) {
            $this->storeManager        = $storeManager;       
            $this->imageFileUploader = $imageFileUploader;
            parent::__construct($context);
            
        }
    
        /**
         * Image upload action
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
         */
        public function execute()
        {        
            $result = $this->imageFileUploader->saveImageToMediaFolder('myimgaeupload');
            return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
        }
    }
```

**step 3:** Create another controller to load the layout
app/code/Vendor/MuModule/Controller/Index/Index.php

File : Index.php

```
<?php
    
    namespace Vendor\MyModule\Controller\Index;
    
    
    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $_pageFactory;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
            {
            $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
             return parent::__construct($context);
        }
    
        public function execute()
        {
         

   
       
        $resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create(); 
       return $resultPage; 
    }
}
```

**step 4:** Declare routers for your font-end controller.
***app/code/Vendor/MyModule/etc/frontend/routes.xml***

File : **routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="*myupload*" frontName="*myupload*">
            <module name="Vendor_MyModule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**step 5:** Declare layout.xml
***/app/code/Vendor/MyModule//view/frontend/layout/myupload_index_index.xml***

File : **myupload_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">             
             <block class="Vendor\MyModule\Block\Myblock" name="myupload_index_index" template="Vendor_MyModule::form.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>       
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 6:** Create the block class file
***/app/code/Vendor/MyModule/Block/Myblock.php***

File : **Myblock.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Block;


class Myblock  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    
    
}
```

**step 7:** create phtml file

***/app/code/Vendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml***

File : **form.phtml**

```
<h2>Welcome to Ny Image Uploader</h2>
<div class="upload-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'uploader'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
   ".upload-wrapper": {
       "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
               "uploader": {                   
                   "component":"Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader",                   
                   "template": "ui/form/element/uploader/uploader",                   
                   "previewTmpl":"Vendor_MyModule/image-preview",
                   "dataScope" : "myimgaeupload",
                   "uploaderConfig": {
                        "url": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('myupload/index/uploadimage'); ?>"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

</script>
```

**step 8:** create KO template file for image preview
***app/code/Vendor/MyModule/view/frontend/web/template/image-preview.html***

File : **preview.html**

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview">
        <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <img
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name">
        </a>

        <div class="actions">
            <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**step 9)** Run following CLI commands

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sydo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to include this in a form?

Comment: @BrandonIrwin - in the image-preview.html template you can add this: <input type="hidden" name="logo" attr="value: $parent.getFilePreview($file)"/> then listen for the POST variable logo