# magento 2 : how can i add image using ui component to database form my ADD NEW DATA UI FORM using model not block

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, image-upload

I have searched a lot but couldn't find exact method for uploading image using ui component. If some one help that will be appreciable .. thanks

Comment: Try following, let me know if you still face any issue. https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-ui-component-image-upload/

Comment: You can check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211985/how-to-recreate-magento-2-backend-image-upload-in-frontend/253017#253017.